# Queue jumping vs (Subjectivism, relativism, utilitarianism)

Tags: utilitarianism, subjectivity, relativism

You are standing in the queue to take the elevator. X who arrived later than you ignore the queue and pushes ahead to enter the elevator. You try to stop him and convince him that breaking the queue is morally wrong.

What would be X’s response if he/she held a subjectivist view on morality?
What would be X’s response if he/she held a relativist view on morality?
What would be X’s response if he/she held a utilitarian view on morality?

Comment: We do not do users' HW assignments here. For help, add the context of the class and your own thoughts on the subject to the post.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. You need to narrow the focus to a single question, provide context, and maybe provide some references.